# Hibernate envers how to update deletion record

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project that is using hibernate envers in order to use audit database.I can see audit records in the audit database successfully.The entities that i am using has two column which holds the id of the recorder user and the id of the updater user for that entity.

I can see the audit record for the deletion in the audit database however i was expecting the updater user id to be updated after deletion but the updater user id is not being updated.

My question is how can i make the updater id of the deletion record with the user id who deletes that record at my database.Is this possible with a configuration? If not how can this be possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some couple of test i realized that hibernate is using AuditEventListener .

After extending audit event listener and overriding the onPostDelete of  metod  AuditEventListener class,  i could do what i am  trying to do.The  deletion audit record could be updated by updating it in this metod.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at the Envers manual?

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#revisionlog

Fairly straightforward. You just need a mechanism to get a handle on your logged in User in the Listener.

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(ExampleListener.class)
public class ExampleRevEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
}



public class ExampleListener implements RevisionListener {
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        ExampleRevEntity exampleRevEntity = (ExampleRevEntity) revisionEntity;

        User user = //get logged in user from some context.
        exampleRevEntity.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow to access historic tables, only revinfo table

Comment: @FazoM. A downvote?  I have absolutely no idea what you are wittering on about...

Comment: Then don't post answers if you have no idea. ;)

Comment: I can give you more details why your answer falls into common pitfall if you want... cheers

Comment: Let's hear it then. The question is about recording the username of user making an edit. it works perfectly and I have no idea what you mean by accessing 'historic tables'. You can go and downvote this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130922/hibernate-envers-spring-web-app-how-to-log-username and maybe write to the author of the envers docs and put him right while you're at it. http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/